# Не отображается svg схема в php файле

Tags: php, svg

Всем привет!

Я не имею опыта работы с svg, нужна помощь.

Сам файл name.svg, если его открыть в браузере, отображается нормально.
Но если я саму схему в виде тега < svg >содержание< /svg> вставляю в < div> в php файле, то схема на сайте не отображается. С остальными схемами все ok, проблема только в оставшихся пяти схемах.
Даю ссылки примеры правильного и проблемного файла:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OaLCzW-3oXVS0uWGBSc2gGNeQ2us4cMb

Понимаю, что вопрос может быть составлен некорректно или чего-то не хватает.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным кейсом? Есть мысли из-за чего так может происходить? Буду рад любой помощи. Может тут есть гуру svg файлов)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!
Дело выло в теге foreignObject. Удалил его и все заработало.
Может кто знает почему так?)